# Should I include web links in my statement of purpose?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, statement-of-purpose

In my statement of purpose, I want to include a web link to give details on research projects that I've worked on. I was wondering if it's a good idea.

JeffE [recommended](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/1555/14716) the practice, although I'm not sure if his recommendation is limited to the CS area. I also worry that this may be seen as a way to circumvent the length restrictions on the SOP.

Comment: Relevant: [Should I link my research in my SOP?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14166/14341)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My feeling is that whether including a link is a good idea or a bad idea depends on how you are using it.  A statement of purpose should be a generally self-contained document.  Thus:

- If your statement of purpose is difficult to fully comprehend without following the link, it would be in a problem (whether in computer science or elsewhere)
- If the statement of purpose is complete without the link, however, and the link is essentially an faster alternative to googling for more information, then I would find it a useful courtesy to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time your statement of purpose is likely being just skimmed or ignored altogether because the search committee doesn't want to spend the time reading more than they have to. As a result, I can't imagine too many of them wanting to go the extra step to view a webpage too.

Regardless, your statement of purpose will likely reflect briefly on anything significant from your previous work that is relevant to the position your applying to. If you cannot succinctly include it in the statement, then leave this job up to your CV.